# Control rig sequence is not in UE4 menu

Tags: animation, unreal-4

In the Unreal Engine [docs](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/AnimatingObjects/SkeletalMeshAnimation/ControlRig/index.html), it is mentioned that, in order to create a `Animation Sequence` using the Control Rig, it is possible to create a `ControlRig Sequence`.
Now, why do I need that?
I need it to create Animation Sequences for my character and I do not want to create the Animation Sequence in other softwares, like Blender.
So why I can not find  `ControlRig Sequence` in UE4 menus?